# What is correct way to start ASP.NET core application, when SQL connection fails

Tags: asp.net-core

I have a ASP.NEt core 2.1 server that is started on-demand. So when someone enters to the web page. My SQL server is in the other location than the web server and there is cases when the SQL server is not up and runnig. So I would need to gracefully start the web server without the SQL server. But so that it of course tries to connect to the SQL server first.

This was working somehow in the ASP.NET Core 1.1, but now with 2.1 I'm getting the exception InvalidOperationException: No database provider has been configured for this DbContext.

I'm using dynamic connection string and I have a function that either returns the connection string, of some other info (like if failure is detected already before.)

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        string connectionString = getConnectionString();
        try
        {
            base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
            if (connectionString != "failure")
            {
                optionsBuilder
                    .EnableSensitiveDataLogging(true)
                    .ReplaceService<IMigrationsAnnotationProvider, CustomAnnotationProvider>()
                    .UseSqlServer(connectionString);
            }
            else
            {
                optionsBuilder
                    .EnableSensitiveDataLogging(true)
                    .ReplaceService<IMigrationsAnnotationProvider, CustomAnnotationProvider>();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            setConnectionStatus(CONNECTION_STATUS_FAILURE, ex.Message);
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

So what I need to do in this OnConfiguring method, if I know that connection will fail, or can I do something in the exception handler ?

Comment: It seems that this issue is no longer valid. It looks like that the latest .Net core SDK (2.1.700) and .Net core runtimes (2.1.11) contain something that fixed this issue.